# YiiBooster Navbar target _blank

Tags: yii, frameworks, widget, yii-booster

I am using the navbar of the extension Yiibooster, but I am having problems with a subitem of the menu, I need to go to a new tab, but I can't make it.

```
<?php $this->widget(
    'bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',
    array(
        'brand' => '<img src ="' . Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/images/FAVICON.png" />Inicio',
        'fixed' => false,
        'collapse' => true,
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                'items' => array(
array(
                        'label' => 'Informes',
                        'items' => array(
                            array('label' => 'Listado de Activos', 'url' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ZfInmuebles/verpdf',
                                'itemOptions' => array('target' => '_blank')),
                        )),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `class=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu'` like

```
 'items' => array(
            array(
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
                'submenuOptions' => array('target' => '_blank'),
                'items' => array(
                    array('label' => 'Listado de Activos', 
                               'url' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ZfInmuebles/verpdf',
                                                                 ),
                )
            )
```

Comment: what does not work? does not it show anything? or url is not working?

Comment: the target still _self, no _blank

Comment: itemoptions is not defined in TbMenu

Comment: ok, i have edited my answer please see the edit. Also if it does not work then put the submenuOptions inside the submenu. Actually its a bit tricky so needs testing different options

Answer (score 1):

If you want go to blank only in one item of the menu, this is the best option:

```
'items' => array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Informes',
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Listado de Activos', 
                 'url' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ZfInmuebles/verpdf',
                 'linkOptions' => array(
                     'target' => '_blank'
                 ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Yii CMenu docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu#items-detail

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$brandOptions`](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap/doc/api/2.2/yii-bootstrap-navbar#$brandOptions-detail):

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'Label text',
    'brandUrl' => '/'.Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'brandOptions' => [
        'target'=>'_blank'
    ],
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',   
    ],
]);
```